# Update WordPress user_meta Custom Field with post_meta Custom Field value

Tags: php, wordpress, forms, custom-fields

I have a front end application, which does what follows:

1. on a WordPress default page, user selects some options (Custom Fields)
2. This data is passed to the user_meta Custom Fields when post is submitted

The options selected on the front-end are Custom Fields (post_meta), the fields in the User profile to update are also Custom fields, but in this case user_meta custom Fields

I have many Fields, some have single values, others are with many options (checkboxes Custom Field with 6 options)

My Code does correctly pass the values form all Posts Custom Fields chosen in the front end to the user profile Custom Fields as long the fields are single value fields

When it comes to the checkboxes, it does not update the user fields pendant

The checkboxes field has as said 6 options, so it is not a single value, but I assume a array of values.

This is my code, please see inline comments

the code works very well as long the Custom Fields and User Profile Fields include only ONE value

```
function user_save_data_action($post_id, $form_data) {

if ($form_data['id']==210) {

    //get curretn user's ID
    $user_id = get_current_user_id();

    //get skype field value suer submits in post (single value)
    $skype = get_post_meta( $post_id, 'wpcf-skype', true );
    //update the user field with this value
    update_user_meta($user_id, 'wpcf-skype', $skype);

    //repeats as above
    $phone = get_post_meta( $post_id, 'wpcf-phone-number', true );
    update_user_meta($user_id, 'wpcf-phone', $phone);
    $pic = get_post_meta( $post_id, 'wpcf-profile-photo', true );
    update_user_meta($user_id, 'wpcf-profile-image', $pic);



    //now the trouble part, this is a checkboxes field, 6 options can be chosen (languages) before submitting the post
    //the Custom Field (for post) name is wpcf-languages

    //get the values form the Custom Field that user submits
    //my checkbox field with 6 options, false because I want a array, right?
    $langs = get_post_meta( $post_id, 'wpcf-languages', false);

    //separate the options received, get the value of each option of the Custom Field (checkboxes wpcf-languages)
    $new_lang = array();
      foreach( $langs as $lang ) {
                $new_lang[] = $lang->value;
       }

    //then update the Wordpress user_meta profile field (custom field as well, name is wpcf-support-languages)
    update_user_meta($user_id, 'wpcf-support-languages', $new_lang);



   //below I do some other staff that also correctly works.
                           //Update slug with user_name
                           $custom_title = wp_get_current_user();
                           $new_title = $custom_title->user_login;

                           //collect data and define new title
                           $my_post = array(
                               'ID'               => $post_id,
                               'post_name' => $new_title,
                               'post_title'=> $new_title,

                           );

                           // Update the post into the database
                           wp_update_post( $my_post );

                           }
                           }
                           add_action('cred_save_data',  'user_save_data_action',10,2);
```

It is worth mentioning that I have tried many different approaches, I won't share them all here because it would simply clutter the post with non-working code.

Basically, I know I must somehow get all options from wpcf-languages, then update all options in wpcf-support-languages

I have done all the var_dump etc, the problem is, I don't need to know "what" it returns (I already know, it returns 6 options, value either checked or not)

I need to know how to update the user fields with.

I can, retrieving manually form DB, update the user meta_fields passing the name and value of each field in a array like this:

```
$lang_array = array(
"wpcf-fields-checkboxes-option-9f3e73c981257b02b9ea5dd006b8fcf9-1" => $English,
"wpcf-fields-checkboxes-option-ea8fcf9b3859a64eed39e169c9d6e42e-1" => $German,
"wpcf-fields-checkboxes-option-b9e50423feb4d0adcd90a7a0a9dc34d6-1" => $Spanish,
"wpcf-fields-checkboxes-option-e7f388081cbee7db725dec32df09b30f-1" => $French,
"wpcf-fields-checkboxes-option-574adb7dec19fad81973a4c3b323b898-1" => $Italian,
"wpcf-fields-checkboxes-option-e2d4422868a74ea8cbc85ab2d70943f7-1" => $Arabic,
"wpcf-fields-checkboxes-option-8ee5abd3454446fb0423a6c5300126b9-1" => $Russian,
"wpcf-fields-checkboxes-option-16d64ea0842251287f056a9eebecf756-1" => $Chinese,);       

update_user_meta($user_id, $lang_array , $lang);
```

But anyone can see, this is NOT what I want, this will ALWAYS set ALL options to "true" and user still can't edit his WordPress Profile choosing from Front-End just as he can do with single fields as Skype, Phone, etc.

Any solution or point-to is very welcome

Comment: my question is quiet simple. how to get data from post_meta custom field, pass it to user_meta custom field. read the post, it is clear where I success, where I struggle, what I have done, what I have tried. If I would have shared here ALL my experiments I have made, some smart ass would have said: "HA! try to keep it simple". IF I would have kept it simple, some body would have sai: "HA! try to elaborate". I suggest, if you have no clue, don't answer. sorry.

Comment: LOL nutjob. "How to get data from post_meta custom field, pass it to user_meta custom field?" is a simple question. You're rambling post isn't. Don't you think if you asked a simple question it would have been answered already?

Comment: Take a pol, does anyone else think his post represents a simple question? And I have a clue, rambling, stupid questions that aren't focused on anything are specifically discouraged on this site. It brings down the quality of the Q&A.

Comment: So perhaps you want me to ask "How to get data from post_meta custom field, pass it to user_meta custom field?" and then wait for the answer:
"What have you tried, can you share code, please don't ask just for solution, share what you have tried."

Can we stop discussing non-post related stuff and get to the "core"?

How would you like me to reformulate my post? I am sure I can learn from your wisdom. I appreciate.

Comment: As you may have noted, I shared my code with a comment:"the code works very well as long the Custom Fields and User Profile Fields include only ONE value". This is why I shared the whole part of my code. So we can see, that it works, as long the CF are single fields. It breaks at the point of Checkboxes (multi options). I re-read the question many times, and it is pretty clear I struggle with "Update WordPress user_meta Custom Field with post_meta Custom Field value" (Title) > "When it comes to the checkboxes, it does not update the user fields pendant" (Text-Body).

Comment: And if you think my question is stupid and rambling, perhaps you can enlighten me, share your wisdom, I am sure with your experience you could point me to the error I make when retrieving the data from the checkboxes (note here, I set 3rd $arg to false) (to get array) (as peer codex instruction).

Comment: I also just googled the word "rambling" (as I am stupid, and not native english speaker, I tried to increase my knowledge) And I see what it means. and I don't agree. The post is not rambling. I share a Title, a issue, 1 function. The function works, it is mentioned where the problem is, the different WORKING options are also mentioned. I am now eager waiting for your surely way more deep insight in StackOverflow, WordPress and PHP.